# Jquery Backstretch doesn't work with user div's - Only with the body element

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-backstretch, debian-jessie

I'm using the  [backstretch](http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/) jquery plugin on a Debian 8 / chrome 57.0.2987.98 installation. It works perfectly with the body element but not with other div's.

I've read a lot of post avec internet but none with a solution.

the example bellow works fine making the image covering the whole page background

```
<script>
    $.backstretch("image.jpg");
</script>
```

Although the documentation states that the code allows to stretch the image over a user div, but it doesn't.

```
<script>
    $(".myclass").backstretch("image.jpg");
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    $("#mydiv").backstretch("image.jpg");
</script>
```

A lot of blogs like this one http://www.dotpointing.com.au/backstretch-js-quick-use/ show usage example .. it seems to work .. but I can't get out ..

Any idea ... ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just insert a white space in divs you declared .. null object not taken in account by this lib .. that works fine